# C++: polymorphism, initialization lists and const variables

Tags: c++

Assume I have 2 classes:

```
class A {
private:
    int x;
    const int y;
public:
    A(int x) : x(x) {}
    virtual foo() = 0;
}

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int x, int y) : A(x), y(y) {}
}
```

This is my understanding of what will happen when the constructor of B is called:

The last line of this code is not good, because the const int y is a member of A, and therefore it is implicitly initialized when we call the constructor of A. So we can't initialize it again in the constructor of B. Because it's const.

How can I initialize y through the constructor of B, while it is still const and still defined in A?

In other words, I want to call the initialization list of A, then the initialization list of B, then the body of A, then the body of B.

**EDIT:**
To rephrase my question:
Assume I have an abstract class A, which B and C inherit from.
I want to save a const variable X in each sub-class of A. The value of X is determined by which sub-class we're in (B/C). How should the initialization work?

Comment: `A(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}` and then `B(int x, int y) : A(x, y) {}` ?

Comment: But your `B` is not (yet) constructible at all, as it doesn't override the pure virtual `foo` function. And the `foo()` declaration is wrong, also - no type specified.

Comment: *...therefore it is implicitly initialized when we call the constructor of A* No, it isn't. You have to provide an initial value for `y`, somewhere. Most likely in the c'tor. Otherwise, what value should it be implicitly initialized with?

Comment: "*I want to call the initialization list of A, then the initialization list of B, then the body of A, then the body of B*" - that is not how constructors work. `A` will be *fully* constructed before `B`, thus the body of `A` will run immediately after the initialization list of `A` is done, and then the body of `B` will run immediately after the initialization list of `B` is done, and so on.

Comment: If `y` is declared as a member of `A` it __has__ to be initialized in the ctor of `A`, period.

Comment: It is not legal to name a member of a base class in the derived class's mem-initializer-list. That is, `B(int x, int y) : A(x), y(y) {}` is just a compiler error (among several other less relevant errors in the code).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I initialize y through the constructor of B, while it is still const and still defined in A?

`A`'s constructor must fully initialize `A`, and therefore it must initialize `y`. If it cannot do so on its own, it must be supplied the information to do so.

```
class A {
private:
    int x;
    const int y;
public:
    A(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
}
```

`B` must supply that information:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    B(int x, int y) : A(x, y) {}
}
```

> In other words, I want to call the initialization list of A, then the initialization list of B, then the body of A, then the body of B.

That wouldn't solve anything. The initialization list of `B` cannot initialize members of `A`, and the body of either cannot initialize a const member. So even if you had the ability to order things in this manner, which we don't, the only place to initialize `y` is the initialization list of `A`, same as before.

> EDIT: To rephrase my question: Assume I have an abstract class A, which B and C inherit from. I want to save a const variable X in each sub-class of A. The value of X is determined by which sub-class we're in (B/C). How should the initialization work?

The constructor of `A` can take a parameter with which to initialize the const member and the derived class constructor can pass it.